# How to convert a Byte array to an integer and then into a string, to display the integer value?

Tags: java, string, integer, arrays, byte

I am trying to take bytes and display them as an integer in android. I am using the bluetooth chat as a template, and am sending data from a bluetooth device, which is working fine and displaying fine. Now, instead of displaying the char set of the byte that is being sent, I want to display the integer value. This is the code from the Handle in the Bluetooth Chat developer code.

```
byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

// construct a string from the buffer
String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);

mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
```

I have tried making the byte array an integer array, which works however, I cannot get an integer array into a string... Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "the integer value"?  The ASCII code?  The numeric conversion, "0" -> 0, "1" -> 1, etc?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ByteBuffer assuming you know the byte order (big vs little endian)

```
byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

// construct a string from the buffer
String writeMessage = String.valueOf(ByteBuffer.wrap(writeBuf).getInt()));
```

If you want little endian you can use `.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`

Comment: +1 Very cool. I haven't used `ByteBuffer` before. Looks *really* useful for avoiding the pain and code bloat of dealing with a `byte[]`. P.S. Pick an avatar sometime!

Comment: Similarly you can get (byte), getLong, getDouble, getFloat, getShort etc and a combination of these (you can have a byte[] with comination of data types)  You can also build a byte[] from primitives as well.